# Can't edit some contentcontrols

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a MS Word with a number of contentcontrols on it. I am trying to populate it with data from a database. The code makes it through the first 22 contentcontrols with no problem....BUT then on number 23 I get an error that it can't be edited because it is protected. I skip it and then the code runs until number 37 and the same thing happens. I've checked and none of the contentcontrols have the box for "contents cannot be edited" checked. I've even written code to make sure that property is set to false and nothing works. Some of the contentcontrols can be written into and others can't with no reason why.

Oh and I can type new data into them with no issue and save the document.